# How to save a bitmap to external storage(kotlin)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am making a project that generates qr code. When user generates a qr code, A download button appears on the screen. If the user clicks this button. Application should save the image(qr code) to external storage. I only want to create a function to save the qr code. But i could not find any useful source. How can i save a bitmap to external storage?

Answer (score 0):

use this function and pass `bitmap` on `button` click

from fragment

```
saveBitmapInStorage(bitmap!!, requireContext())
```

from activity

```
saveBitmapInStorage(bitmap!!, this)
```

main function

```
open fun saveBitmapInStorage(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context) {
        val filename = "QR_"+"${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
        var fos: OutputStream? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            context.contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                }
                val imageUri: Uri? =
                        resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
                fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
            }
        } else {
            val imagesDir =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
            fos = FileOutputStream(image)
        }
        fos?.use {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
        }
    }
```

why I share because I'm using this code in my current project and its working for me

hope helpful for you.

Comment: Welcome @UtkuBerkayTAN glad to help you